# Can I use delete query on same table twice during transaction?

Tags: php, mysql

Can I use delete query on same table twice during transaction ?
I have two array want to delete same table before commit, if one fail hope can make it rollback, but there some error if I use below 2 delete query one time. I can't find what's wrong..

```
  $connect_db_x_article->beginTransaction();

  // image
  if (!empty($data['gallery_old']['gallery_old_delete']['gallery_old_image_delete_id'])) {
    for ($i=0; $i < count($data['gallery_old']['gallery_old_delete']['gallery_old_image_delete_id']); $i++) {
      $file_id = $data['gallery_old']['gallery_old_delete']['gallery_old_image_delete_id'][$i];

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM article_gallery WHERE id = :id";
      $stmt = $connect_db_article->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindValue(':id', $file_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      $sql = "DELETE FROM article_gallery WHERE id = :id";
      $stmt = $connect_db_article->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindValue(':id', $row[0]['id']);
      $stmt->execute();

      $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$base_uri.'/assets/images';
      $folder_path = $path.'/'.$id;
      $file_path = $folder_path.'/'.$row[0]['file_name'].'.'.$row[0]['file_format'];
      if (is_file($file_path)) {
        unlink($file_path);
      }
    }
  }

  // video_embed
  if (!empty($data['gallery_old']['gallery_old_delete']['gallery_old_video_embed_delete_id'])) {
    for ($i=0; $i < count($data['gallery_old']['gallery_old_delete']['gallery_old_video_embed_delete_id']); $i++) {
      $file_id = $data['gallery_old']['gallery_old_delete']['gallery_old_video_embed_delete_id'][$i];

      $sql = "DELETE FROM article_gallery WHERE id = :id";
      $stmt = $connect_db_article->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindValue(':id', $file_id);
      $stmt->execute();
    }
  }

  $connect_db_article->commit();
```

Comment: You can do anything you like, including deleting twice. Or 10 000 times for that matter. Transaction just guarantees that your queries will either ALL be executed and stored to HDD, or none if any query fails. Therefore, you're safe. As for your code - it's suboptimal. Prepared statements are **prepared once, executed multiple times**. Why would you prepare the same delete statements three times? Just supply a different parameter for `id` and execute it.

Comment: Thanks for reply and description!!